# Add internal padding to tkinter label while using .place()

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-label

Is there a way to add internal padding to label while using place() geometry manager?

I have tried
*ipadx* option is not there...

```
Label(text = "Something", bg = "blue").place(x = 0, y = 0)
```

Comment: Try adding `pady=10` inside the `Label(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
l = Label(text = "Something", bg = "blue")
l.pack(ipadx = 1) # change 1 to whichever value you want
```

Comment: When you call `.pack(...)`, the `.place(...)` is ignored so there is no point to having both of them.

Comment: I edited it, I just added it in because .pack() was in the question too.

Comment: @leaves thanks for answering... my application is quite long and I have to use place() everywhere... so I can't try your solution

Comment: @PrakharParikh instead of using the ```.place(...)``` method or ```.pack(...)``` method you can use ```.grid(...)``` if you want to position your widgets as well as add internal padding